# MATLAB GUI: Different results when opening a figure file using GUIDE and straightaway

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have made a MATLAB GUI but I am facing a problem. The problem is that when I open the GUI figure file straightaway, the resulting GUI does not work properly(I am guessing there is a problem with the loading of the opening_function). But when I open that figure file using GUIDE, I am getting proper results. I want the GUI figure to run properly when I click on it. I have provided the link for my GUI figure file and the M-file for the same in the below link using Google drive:
[Google drive link for GUI figure file and code file (along with an image required for the working of the two)](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4MbckCJ2oPWWkxaci1Ha2hBaVk&usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

your google drive link is not working. also if its your account of google drive which you have used to login then i can't access the files in it...use some other file hosting services to share the screenshot.
also you can always debug your callback functions using breakpoints to check why its not working properly.

Comment: Is the google drive page opening when you click on the link?? If yes and the files are not opening, I think the google drive works only when you log into google services through any google account. Although there is no preview for the first file but there is download option for the same. Remaining things you can preview.

Comment: I tried opening the link in a friend's laptop through his google account and it worked.

Comment: I just found out the answer on a mathworks website. It says that do not attempt to run a GUIDE GUI by opening its FIG-file outside of GUIDE. If you do so, the figure opens and appears ready to use, but the GUI does not initialize and its callbacks do not function.